# Can't make drop-down hover work

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I am trying to make a drop-down menu that drops from image but I can't seem to make it work. How should I target the hover? Because everything I am trying is not working. How I am trying to initiate hover effect is shown at the end of CSS.

```css
.area-left {
  float: left;
}

.menu-icon {
  width: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu-icon hr {
  border: 2px solid #A5CF4C;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.area-left .menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(165, 207, 76, 0.4);
}

.logo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.sub-menu ul {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.sub-menu li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.sub-menu .menu li:first-child {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.sub-menu ul li {
  display: none;
}

.logo img:hover .sub-menu ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="area-left">
  <ul id="htc-menu" class="parent-menu">
    <li class="logo ico-container">
      <div class="menu-icon">
        <hr/>
        <hr/>
        <hr/>
      </div><img src="images/logo.png" alt="HTC Logo"></li>
    <li class="sub-menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.htc.com/us/smartphones-learn/">smartphones</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.htc.com/us/accessories/">accessories</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.vive.com/us/">virtual reality</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.htc.com/us/fitness/ua-healthbox/">fitness</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could set up a Plunkr or JSFiddle with the work you currently have..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access the `.sub-menu` as a child of `.logo`, despite them being siblings of each other.

Try:

```css
.logo:hover + .sub-menu ul li  {
    display: block;
}
```

Or just:

```css
#htc-menu:hover .sub-menu ul li  {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: For further reference, see [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

Comment: Thank You very much! This works! Ahh, I see - I will keep this in mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :)

I purposely did not go with the adjacent CSS selector because once your mouse moves off the menu icon, the menu would disappear again, making it unhelpful. So you'll want to target the hover state of the parent element so that the menu remains visible while the mouse moves from the logo to the menu that just appears.

```css
.area-left {
  float: left;
}

.menu-icon {
  width: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu-icon hr {
  border: 2px solid #A5CF4C;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.area-left .menu li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(165, 207, 76, 0.4);
}

.logo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.sub-menu ul {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.sub-menu li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.sub-menu .menu li:first-child {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.sub-menu ul li {
  display: none;
}

.logo img:hover .sub-menu ul li {
  display: block;
}


/* Tessa's Changes */

#htc-menu {
  list-style: none;
}

#htc-menu:hover li.sub-menu ul.menu li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="area-left">
  <ul id="htc-menu" class="parent-menu">
    <li class="logo ico-container">
      <div class="menu-icon">
        <hr/>
        <hr/>
        <hr/>
      </div><img src="images/logo.png" alt="HTC Logo">
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.htc.com/us/smartphones-learn/">smartphones</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.htc.com/us/accessories/">accessories</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.vive.com/us/">virtual reality</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.htc.com/us/fitness/ua-healthbox/">fitness</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Superb - this the disappearing was my next problem :D Thank you so much!